# Вывести повторяющиеся имена, которые находятся в файлe (n log n)

Tags: c++, алгоритм

В текстовом файлe есть несколько массивов имён. Нужно отделить и вывести на экран те имена, которые есть во всех массивах. Сложность программы не должна превысить `Const*O(n log n)`. n это размер самово большово массива в файле... Число  массивов в файле случайное. Программа должна писаться на *C++*.

Какой   алгоритм  использовать?

Comment: Хотя бы, что такое n написали...

Comment: @andy.37, почитайте [Вычислительная сложность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: @LEQADA, представьте, читал. А Вы понимаете, что есть n в данной задаче? Общее к-во имен? Число массивов? Длина самого большого массива? Или, м.б. число жителей Воронежа?

Comment: n это размер самово большово массива в файле...знаю что такое сложность  алгоритма. но не могу  найти такои алгоритм

Comment: @andy.37, ну читали и читали. Молодец. А что я такого сказал?

Comment: @Aram, я понимаю, что русский язык для Вас не родной. Большая просьба, пару слов об этом вопросе, пока не увидел ник, Ваш текст не вызывал ничего, кроме раздражения. Это так, на будущее.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Загружаем первый массив, кладем элементы как ключи в

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, bool> m;
```

это будет примерно за O(n).
Ключи `m` - имена, значения - равны `false`.

Читаем элементы следующего массива, если элемент есть в `m`, выставляем значение в `true`.

```
auto it = m.find(x);
if (it != m.end())
  it->second = true;
```

Теперь если значение в `m` равно `true` - то элемент был в обоих массивах.
Удаляем из `m` все элементы у которых значение равно `false`.

Повторяем для остальных массивов - читаем элементы, ищем их в `m`, меняем значение. Вторым циклом удаляем лишние элементы.

Comment: Abyx  а для понимание  этого  какие темы  нужно знать в с++

Comment: Abyx  а кагда мы по очереди читаем массивы это уже не второй цикл ?  хачу сказать  уже не получается n^2 ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Записываем массивы в один массив в виде пар `(Имя, номер массива)`, в случае большого массива -- в файл.
2. Применяем к полученному массиву (или файлу) подходящий алгоритм сортировки со сложностью **O(n log n)** и операцией сравнения `Имя1 == Имя2 ? Номер1 < Номер2 : Имя1 < Имя2`. (Операцию стоит оптимизировать так, чтобы было одно сравнение строк, а не два)
3. Фильтруем результат выводя только те имена, которые имеют полностью все номера. Так как они будут идти по порядку, сложность этой операции не превысит **n**.

Answer (score 0):

Можно гораздо быстрее.
Используем `std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map`
Дальше псевдокод:

```
for (int i=0; i<number_of_arrays; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j<array[i].size(); j++) {
     if (map.count(array[i][j])) { // проверяем наличие ключа 
        map[array[i][j]]++; // увеличиваем значение счетчика
     } else {
        map.emplace(array[i][j], 1); // добавляем элемент со счетчиком 1
     }
   }
}
// Из map осталось выбрать ключи со счетчиком равным number_of_arrays
```

Два замечания:

1) работает с неповторяющимися строками в массивах. Доработать несложно, один break для внешнего цикла.

2) использовать map c уникальными ключами будет быстрее

3) сложность O(m*n*log(n)) - где m - число массивов, log(n) (ЕМНИП, но больше не должно быть) - стоимость поиска ключа в map

Необходимо знать std::string, std::vector, std::map (std::unordered_map)

Comment: andy.37  а так не превышает ли сложность алгоритма  n log n?

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что алгоритм со сложностью, не зависящей от числа массивов будет весьма нетривиален, если вообще возможен. Поправочка, доработка для массивов с возможно повторяющимися строками будет не так уж тривиальна.

Comment: ладно ..спосибо очень